# Android: Unable to instantiate application error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this error when running my apk:

```
09-20 14:08:57.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 14:08:57.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.soinfit.serverAndServices.ErrorReport: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.soinfit.serverAndServices.ErrorReport" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soinfit-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.soinfit-1, /system/lib]]
09-20 14:08:57.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5430):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
09-20 14:08:57.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
```

I have read all the topics about this issue on stackoverflow and no one helped me.

- I cleaned my project
- Checked order and export

My application project is this class:

```
package serverAndServices;

import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportField;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

import serverAndServices.ServerUtilities;
import android.app.Application;

import com.soinfit.R;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dGVacG0ydVHnaNHjRjVTUTEtb3FPWGc6MQ",

customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
        ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
        ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.BUILD,
        ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT, ReportField.DEVICE_ID }, formUri = ServerUtilities.ERROR_REPORT_FILE, mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional,
                                                                                                                                                                                                            // default
                                                                                                                                                                                                            // false
resToastText = R.string.error_happned)

public class ErrorReport extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(ErrorReport.this);
    }

}
```

In my manifest I have this code:

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.soinfit"
    android:versionCode="36"
    android:versionName="1.16" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.soinfit.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.soinfit.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:name=".serverAndServices.ErrorReport"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false"      
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="soInFitMain.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ProgramPlay" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.SocialPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.RegisterPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.FinishProgramPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ProgramBuilder" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.BuildProgramScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ChooseProgramType" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.SettingChoosePage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ProfilePage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.PersonalDetails" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.PrivacyPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.HomePage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ProgramSettings" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.QandA" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.SentProgramsPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.MyGymPage" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.UsersInClass" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.GymMessages" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.PrivateTrains" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.TrainerClasses" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.TrainersInMyGym" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="soInFitMain.ChallengesPage" >
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name="serverAndServices.ChallengesActionReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >

             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.soinfit.utilities.CHALLENGE_CLICK" />     
               </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="serverAndServices.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.soinfit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="serverAndServices.GcmIntentService" />
        <service android:name="serverAndServices.OnTheWayCounterService" />
        <service android:name="serverAndServices.ProgramTimeCounterService" />
        <service android:name="serverAndServices.SetRestTimeCounterService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My project packages

[image]

Comment: show your packange name in manifest file if possibel

Comment: Added the package name in the manifest

Comment: Are there other applications defined in your manifest?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong about this, but the package definition inside your ErrorReport.java is strange to me. I would use `package com.soinfit.serverAndServices;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package in your custom application is serverAndServices. Making your class serverAndServices.ErrorReport. Android is looking for com.soinfit.serverAndServices.ErrorReport. Which is the name you declared in the manifest. The two should match.

Comment: I opened new package called com.soinfit.serverAndServices